# How can I do a portfolio?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to import the stocks from de APY in the URL and creat a table only with this stocks. I think that the information in the APY not is a JSON recognite

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Variables
stocks = ["Delta Acciones - Clase A","SBS Acciones Argentina - Clase A","MAF Acciones Argentinas - Clase B","IAM Renta Variable - Clase B"]
initial_weight = np.array([0.20,0.30,0.30,0.20])
empresas = {}

prices = requests.get(f'https://api.cafci.org.ar/estadisticas/informacion/diaria/2/2021-07-12/{"fondo"}?serietype=vcp').json ()

prices = pd.DataFrame(prices) 

empresas[fondo] = prices.set_index('fecha')
empresas[fondo] = empresas[fondo]['vcp']

#Concatenate each of the dataframes into a single dataframe
portfolio = pd.concat(empresas, axis=1)
```

I get this error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre]. Please [edit] your question and include the **full text** of the error and traceback. What you have given is not enough.

Comment: Additionally, this code won't run because you haven't defined `fondo` anywhere. Also, why does your f-string URL contain `{"fondo"}` in it? If `fondo` is supposed to be defined previously and you want to use its value in your f-string, you should use `{fondo}` (without the quotes `""`) instead.

Comment: Sorry is my firt time, fondo i put because i copy the code of another person that coding with nasdaq stocks. how can i do?

Comment: I delete fondo a now, only i have 2 head, success and data. In data is all the information not is separatly.

Comment: not much I can do to help as I don't read Spanish... it will all be in API documentation.  Your URL gives a 404 so you don't have the basis of a working API `import requests
requests.get(f'https://api.cafci.org.ar/estadisticas/informacion/diaria/2/2021-07-12/{"fondo"}?serietype=vcp')
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get you the `prices` dataframe. How to manipulate it from here is up to you. I strongly suggest reading the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# remove '{"fondo"}' from the URL entirely
url = "https://api.cafci.org.ar/estadisticas/informacion/diaria/2/2021-07-12/?serietype=vcp"
response = requests.get(url)

# the info you want is in the "data" key in the response
data = response.json()["data"]
prices = pd.DataFrame(data)
```